# Account model "mobile template" differs from "internet template"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Made a portal with the standard MVC 4 "internet template", now would like to disclose some information on mobile devices.

Using the standard “mobile template” the account model differs from the “internet template”.

What is the easiest way to map to the same model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need (to login) using the "internet template" are some small changes:

Use the WebSecurity for the login

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
        {
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
```

Add your RedirectToLocal()

Add WebMatrix. Make a reference to WebMatrix.Data and WebMatrix.WebData. For both Dlls change the properties in the property window and set Copy local True. Next use it:

```
using WebMatrix.WebData;
```

Edit your web.config and change the lines for membership en roleManager

```
<membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Initialize the database connection:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```